# Loading gif during ajax request to add

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have ajax request for adding data and div with gif.
I need to show this gif when uploading content and hide at completion.

Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $("#load-hist").show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("pageCount", "Home")",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ start: true }),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#sidebar-filter-result").html(data);
                    $("#load-hist").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row box-js base-box-form" id="sidebar-filter-result">

                    @Html.Action("ListHistory", "Sidebar")

                </div>
                <p style="text-align: center;">
                    <img id="load-hist" src="~/Content/css/main-load-gif.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display:none" />
                </p>
```

Without `$("#load-hist").show();` and `$("#load-hist").hide();` it's work good, but when I add this gif all breaks down when loading...

Comment: What do you mean by `all breaks down`?

Comment: when I go down to the bottom of the page, it tries to call more data, although all the data is already loaded

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with your if condition, not with a gif or hiding/showing anything. Check your if out `$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()`

Comment: Apparently I need to check before this that there are still records in the database and if they are not there, then the Ajax will not work ...

Comment: I am not getting your if condition $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height(). Do you want call the ajax function in scroll event?